# How do I make this table's padding the same as the above divs?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to add padding to the left and right of this table so it fits in with the above and below divs.

[image: Currently where I'm at]

This is what I'm currently at, and this is where I'm hoping to add padding to.
[image]

I've tried to create an ID "playerstatstable" and apply it to the parenting divs of the table but to no success.

```css
/* Put the template's styles here.
Don't forget to rename the link in index.hmtl */


/* Set height of the grid so .sidenav can be 100% (adjust as needed) */
.row.content {height: 550px}

/* Set gray background color and 100% height */
.sidenav {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 100%;
}
    
/* On small screens, set height to 'auto' for the grid */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .row.content {height: auto;} 
}

#playerstatstable{
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-left:15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    /* Set height of the grid so .sidenav can be 100% (adjust as needed) */
    .row.content {height: 550px}
    
    /* Set gray background color and 100% height */
    .sidenav {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      height: 100%;
    }
        
    /* On small screens, set height to 'auto' for the grid */
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .row.content {height: auto;} 
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse visible-xs">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">St. Louis Cardinals</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Analytics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Export</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-sm-3 sidenav hidden-xs">
      <h2>Logo</h2>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li class="active"><a href="#section1">Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2">Reports</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">Analytics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">Export</a></li>
      </ul><br>
    </div>
    <br>
    
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="well">
        <h4>The Cardinals Dream Team</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well">
            <h4>Users</h4>
            <p>1 Million</p> 
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well">
            <h4>Pages</h4>
            <p>100 Million</p> 
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well">
            <h4>Sessions</h4>
            <p>10 Million</p> 
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="well">
            <h4>Bounce</h4>
            <p>30%</p> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
        <!-- Table -->
      <div class="row" >
            <div class="col-small-12" >
                <div class="well" id="playerstatstable">
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th scope="col">#</th>
                              <th scope="col">First</th>
                              <th scope="col">Last</th>
                              <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <th scope="row">1</th>
                              <td>Mark</td>
                              <td>Otto</td>
                              <td>@mdo</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <th scope="row">2</th>
                              <td>Jacob</td>
                              <td>Thornton</td>
                              <td>@fat</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <th scope="row">3</th>
                              <td>Larry</td>
                              <td>the Bird</td>
                              <td>@twitter</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div> 
            </div>
      </div>
     
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <div class="well">
            <p>Text</p> 
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="well">
            <p>Text</p> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help is welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just edit your style to `col-sm-12`:

```
<!-- Table -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
         The other code is omitted for the brevity
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I completely missed I wrote "small" instead of "sm"
Thank you so much.

Comment: @PoptartKitten I am glad that it helped to you:)